How to prevent type-widening when accessing sub-properties of generic-inferred types
Given the following snippet:
export type Expect<T extends true> = T;
export type Equal<X, Y> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2 ? true : false;

export class Example<T extends { a: boolean }> {
    #param!: T["a"] extends true ? { a: number } : { a: string };
    get wtf() {
        return this.#param.a;
    }
    get thisMakesSense() {
        return this.#param;
    }
}

const ex = new Example<{ a: true }>();
type _Test1 = Expect<Equal<typeof ex.thisMakesSense, { a: number }>>;
type _Test2 = Expect<Equal<typeof ex.wtf, number>>; // Error, it's number | string. why???

I expected the type of ex.wtf to be number.
I tried using explicit return types on get wtf(), but got an error, where this.#param.a was not assignable to the return type of T['a'] extends ...
The only solution is casting, but then I'm masking potential issues.

Does this solution suits your need? playround
Do not hesitate to propose a playground when you ask a question though.

You've run into ms/TS#33181 and the approach I use is to explicitly return the type using indexed accesses as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Seems TS fails here to keep narrowing right, you can annotate yourself with a generic mapping type:
type ExampleParam = {a: boolean};
type Mapping<T extends ExampleParam> = T['a'] extends true ? {a : number} : { a: string};

export class Example<T extends ExampleParam, P extends Mapping<T> = Mapping<T>> {
    #param!: P;
    get wtf(): P['a']{
        return this.#param.a;
    }
    get thisMakesSense() {
        return this.#param;
    }
}

I think getters' typing is less smart, but once you introduce a method and use it in getters, the things usually get better:
type ExampleParam = {a: boolean};
type Mapping<T extends ExampleParam> = T['a'] extends true ? {a : number} : { a: string};

export class Example<T extends ExampleParam, P extends Mapping<T> = Mapping<T>> {
    #param!: P;
    private getParamProp(prop: keyof P){
        return this.#param[prop];
    }
    get wtf(){
        return this.getParamProp('a');
    }
    get thisMakesSense() {
        return this.#param;
    }
}

Another option is to change your type if that appropriate to avoid the failing object union:
export class Example<T extends {a: boolean}> {
    #param!: {a : T['a'] extends true ? number: string};
    get wtf() {
        return this.#param.a;
    }
    get thisMakesSense() {
        return this.#param;
    }
}

